# Process information in Android Device Monitor

Tags: android, android-studio, ddms, android-device-monitor

[image: ADM screenshot]

Confused with the information shown in Android Device Monitor, what does the `8600 / 8700` and `10387` mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your screenshot, *10387* is the process id (**pid**) and *8700* is the static debugging port. *8600* is the port being forwarded to *8700*.

See [Using DDMS](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/ddms.html%22%22).